# How to get the Row index of the active cell in a specific range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I want to get the row index of the active cell
relative to a supplied range...

to clarify I want the index of the row inside of the range

Something like

> RangeRowIndexOfActiveCell( range1 )

should return the row index of active cell relative to the specified range

(-1 if ActiveCell is not inside range... 
but that is superfluous)

?any ideas

Comment: did you try `ActiveCell.row`?

Comment: that give you the active row relative to the worksheet... I want the same information but relative to a range...

Comment: `activecell.row - range1.row + 1`

Comment: Thanks Scott... that will do the trick... I was wondering if excel had this as a native function... that would take care of hidden rows and other quirks...

Answer (score 1):

This prints the index of the activecell within the range, as long as the ranges overlap.

```
Function RangeRowIndexOfActiveCell(ByVal rng As Range) As Long

    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
        RangeRowIndexOfActiveCell = ActiveCell.row - rng.row + 1
    Else
        RangeRowIndexOfActiveCell = -1
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the info.. but this must work even if ranges do not overlap... so I can't use Intersect... the solution above from Scott Craner just solved the problem

Comment: @ZEE I put it together that way because you said you wanted it to return -1 if it was outside of the range...